# I am getting an below error when i run npm install and ng serve on my angular2 application

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Once trying to run the app, this error occurs:

> Parsing angular-cli.json failed. Please make sure your
>   angular-cli.json is valid JSON. Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string
>   in JSON at position 498

My application on
git Repo:https://github.com/kishore1288/Ki-Ng2-SPA-Form

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing comma in your JSON (Line 22):

```
"styles": [
     "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
     "styles.scss" <----
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 ],
```

Valid JSON:

```
 {
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "name": "ki-angular2-spa-form0"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
         "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
         "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [


        "app/core/preloader/preloader.ts",
        "vendor.ts"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON and find errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular-cli.json has a json error , you've forgotten a comma:

```
  "styles": [
    "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
    "styles.scss"
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

should be

```
 "styles": [
    "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
    "styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ]
```

in order to make sure your json is valid , you can put it in [json validator](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/);

Comment: I added comma in after styles.css in json file, now i am unable to see error in build but i am unable to see output vie in browser.